# Change TextField InputDecoration LabelText position and CounterText position as suffix

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to animate LabelText below the TextField?
I am imagining that as soon as textfield becomes focused, the hintText should animate towards HelperText
Another problem, is there any way to set CounterText (I want to use maxVal in TextField, so counterText is updated automatically) as Suffix of Textfield
How shall I approach this ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TextField, you can use TextField or TextFormField and set it's enabled property to false, and use helperText,HintText, Counter Text etc. so it'll act as textfield and you will have all the liberty to use TextFormField too.